# How do I write a SCons script with hard-to-predict dynamic sources?

Tags: scons

I'm trying to set up a build system involving a code generator. The exact files generated are unknown until after the generator is run, but I'd like to be able to run further build steps by pattern matching (run some program on all files with some extension). Is this possible?

Some of the answers here involving code generation seem to assume that the output is known or a listing of generated files is created. This isn't impossible in my case, but I'd like to avoid it since it makes things more complicated.

https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/DynamicSourceGenerator seems to indicate that it's possible to add additional targets during Builder actions, but while I could get the build to run and list the generated files, any build steps introduced don't run.

https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/NonDeterministicDependencies uses Scanners to add build steps. I put a glob(...) in a scanner, and it succeeds in detecting the generated files, but the files are inexplicably deleted before it actually runs the dependent step.

Is this use case possible? And why is SCons deleting my generated files?

## A toy example

### source (the file referenced in SConscript)

An example generator, constructs 3 files (not easily known to the build system) and puts them in the argument folder

```
echo "echo 1" > $1/gen1.txt
echo "echo 2" > $1/gen2.txt
echo "echo 3" > $1/gen3.txt
```

### SConstruct

Just sets up a variant_dir

```
SConscript('SConscript', variant_dir='build')
```

### SConscript

The goal is for it to:

1. "Compile" the generator (in this toy example, just copies a file called 'source' and adds execute permissions
2. Run the "compiled" generator ('source' is a script that generates files)
3. Perform some operation on each of those generated files by extension. This example just runs the "compile" copy operation on them (for simplicity).

---

```
env = Environment()

env.Append(BUILDERS = {'ExampleCompiler' :
                       Builder(action=[Copy('$TARGET', '$SOURCE'),
                                       Chmod('$TARGET', 0755)])})

generator = env.ExampleCompiler('generator', 'source')

env.Append(BUILDERS = {'GeneratorRun' :
                       Builder(action=[Mkdir('$TARGET'),
                                       '$SOURCE $TARGET'])})

generated_dir = env.GeneratorRun(Dir('generated'), generator)
```

Everything's fine up to here, where all the targets are explicitly known to the build system ahead of time.

---

Attempting to use this block of code to glob over the generated files causes SCons to delete (!!) the generated files:

```
for generated in generated_dir[0].glob('*.txt'):
  generated_run = env.ExampleCompiler(generated.abspath + '.sh', generated)
```

---

Attempting to use an action to update the build tree results in additional actions not being run:

```
def generated_scanner(target, source, env):
  for generated in source[0].glob('*.txt'):
    print "scanned " + generated.abspath
    generated_target = env.ExampleCompiler(generated.abspath + '.sh', generated)
    Alias('TopLevelAlias', generated_target)

env.Append(BUILDERS = {'GeneratedOperation' :
                       Builder(action=[generated_scanner])})

dummy = env.GeneratedOperation(generated_dir[0].File('#dummy'), generated_dir)
Alias('TopLevelAlias', dummy)
```

The Alias operations are suggested in above dynamic source generator guide, but don't seem to do anything. The prints do execute and indicate that the action gets run.

Comment: Can you provide more details on the code generator? Commercial product. Internally created? Other?  Is there no reasonable way to scan the sources to predict the output files?  Will the tool generate a list of output files (makedepend type output?)

Comment: The code generator is internally created, basically arbitrary source files (think C++, but actually another less well known language) that are complied into an executable. Scanning the sources to predict the output files isn't feasible (the generator logic isn't straightforward, nor is it fast to run), but it is possible to have the generator create a list of output files.

The simple way out is to have the user specify a list of outputs (which obviously works), but I'd like to know if there's an automatic way to avoid user mistakes and provide a nicer experience.

Comment: How fast would the generator be able to spit out the list of files for an input? (quick or same as running the tool or somewhere in the middle?)  What language?

Comment: It would take about the same amount of time to generate a list of files as to do the actual code generation (so it shouldn't run on every SCons invocation). The generator is written in a custom language, so tooling that might infer generated outputs from sources is also infeasible.

Answer (score 0):

Running some build pattern on special file extensions is possible with SCons. For C/CPP files this is the preferred scheme, for example:

```
env = Environment()
env.Program('main', Glob('*.cpp'))
```

The main task of SCons, as a build system, is to do the minimum amount of work such that all your targets are up-to-date. This makes things complicated for the use case you've described above, because it's not clear how you can reach a "stable" situation where no generated files are added and all targets are built.
You're probably better off by using a simple Python script directly...I really don't see how using SCons (or any other build system for that matter) is mission-critical in this case.

Edit:

At some point you have to tell SCons about the created files (`*.txt` in your example above), and for tracking all dependencies properly, the list of `*.txt` files has to be complete. This the task of the Emitter within SCons, which is responsible for returning the list of resulting target and source files for a Builder call. Note, that these files don't have to exist physically during the "parse" phase of SCons. Please also have a look at my answer to [Scons: create late targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35056538/scons-create-late-targets) , which goes into some more detail.

Once you have a proper Emitter in place (see also https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/ToolsForFools , "Using Emitters") you should be able to use the `Glob('*.txt')` call, which will detect and track your created files automatically.

Finally, on our page "Talks and Slides" ( https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/TalksAndSlides ) you can find my talk from the PyCon FR.2014, "Why SCons is Not Slow", which explains shortly how SCons works internally. This might be helpful in understanding this problem better and coming up with a full solution.

Comment: Scons adds dependency tracking (so builds are incremental and minimal), dependency-based parallelization, and general build rules (instead of writing / copypasting a separate script for each target).

The generator is deterministic based on the inputs that the generator is built from, but there's no easy way to get a manifest of outputs other than running the generator (which is unacceptably slow). So it's stable in that once the generator runs, the output files are known and can be built.

Comment: So the "generator" run shouldn't be part of the SCons build description? You only want to find the generated files after the initial generation step and then keep them up-to-date? In that case, how do you try to put my snippet above to use (code example that deletes your generated files)?

Comment: I'd like the generator run (and compile) to also be part of the build description - the generator code is part of the project and should have its dependencies tracked so it isn't needlessly rebuilt.

Comment: Ok, I've added a toy example which hopefully makes things more clear.